# Android Studio - Define class that requires context and attributes in main activity

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to use a custom class in my main activity.

```
DrawingCanvas drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas();
```

To define the class I have to pass it two arguments. This is my constructor.

```
public DrawingCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

I know I need to do something like below, but I am not sure what to pass for the attributes set.

```
DrawingCanvas drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas(this, );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `DrawingCanvas` is extending from the `View` class or one that inherits from it.

In this case, it's convenient to have the constructors similar to this:

```
    public DrawingCanvas(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DrawingCanvas(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawingCanvas(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // more code…
    }
```

That way you can choose the most adequate one. As you can see, when there's no `AttributeSet`, you can just pass `null`.

Now you would only need to do it like this:

```
DrawingCanvas drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas(this);
```

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you!

Comment: @Pauline Glad it worked! `attrs` and `defStyleAttr` are normally defined in the XML, but if the custom view class doesn't have any custom attributes or styles/themes, then they're not really needed. More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr